# How do I turn a while loop into a recursive method?

Tags: python, recursion, while-loop

I need help turning this while loop into a recursive method? How do I do this?

```
while z <= len(list):
     if z = len(list): #base case
        return something
     else:
        #do something else
     z += 1
```

Comment: don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: what's wrong with http://stackoverflow.com/a/12985127/989121? Why do you post the same question twice?

Comment: was not fully satisfied with the responses from there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def func(my_list, z):

    if z == len(my_list):
        return something
    else:
        # do something else
        return func(my_list, z+1)

z = someValue
print func(my_list, z)
```

You should not use `list` as variable name.

Comment: you should probably put `do something else` in elif

Comment: don't use list as a variable name

Comment: When would you need the else?

Comment: recursive functions is a bad idea in Python though. There is only a limited recursion depth(although it can be increased/decreased) - loops are always simpler and better.

Comment: @Pogo. Aww. Crappy misconstruct.

Comment: @PrototypeStark. Yeah that may be true in some cases. But that's upto OP what he wants to do. Recursion may be useful in some cases.

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'functionname' referenced before assignment
^ I get that error

Comment: I would put an assert to make sure that z < len(my_list) or put an else to break the recusion

Comment: I did do that in fact, I need such a function to be nested into another class method for my program. Could that be a problem?

Comment: @Pogo. You mean somthing like this: - `assert z < len(my_list): funcCall`? Can you give an idea. I haven't used assert in Python.

Comment: @RahulSharma. Then you need to tell your usage explicitly. function inside a method may be a different case.

Comment: Any suggestions regarding how to do this as a nested function without receiving an Unboundlocalerror

Comment: @RahulSharma. Can you post the code, what you are trying to do. That may be because you are using a variable inside a class, that is defined outside.

Comment: @RahulSharma. Are you actually replacing your complete while loop in a method, with this function?

Answer (score 1):

```
z = 1

while z <=5:
    if z == 5:
        print 'base case'
    else:
        print 'repeated text'
    z += 1
```

This is translated to recursive code as follows. You can work on your case based on this

```
def recursion(z):
    assert z <= 5
    if z == 5:
        print 'base case'
    else:
        print 'repeated text'
        recursion(z+1)

recursion(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will implement the recursive function using while loop  ---Factorial----
(1)It will call the fact function recursively based on while condition
(2)You can add if or nested if according to your problem statement

```
def fact(num):
    while num>1:
        return num*fact(num-1)
    else:
        return num

result = fact(3)
print(result)
```

6

Answer (score 0):

```
condition = lambda n: n >= 3
repetition = lambda n: print(f'{n}: Repeating Line')
termination = lambda n: print(f'{n}: Terminal Line')

def recursive(n):
  if condition(n):
    repetition(n)
    n = recursive(n-1)
  else:
    termination(n)
  return n

def iterative(n):
  while condition(n):
    repetition(n)
    n -= 1
  termination(n)
  return n

def main():
  n = 4

  print("Recursion Example")
  result = recursive(n)
  print(f'result = {result}')
  print()

  print("Iteration Example")
  result = iterative(n)
  print(f'result = {result}')
  print()

main()


>>> Recursion Example
>>> 4: Repeating Line
>>> 3: Repeating Line
>>> 2: Terminal Line
>>> result = 2
>>> 
>>> Iteration Example
>>> 4: Repeating Line
>>> 3: Repeating Line
>>> 2: Terminal Line
>>> result = 2
```