# transform Iterative looping over list to recursively looping over list

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code:

```
    for item in word_list:
        if item.count('s') > 1:
            print(item.count('s'))
```

Please tell me how i can change this iterative structure to an recursive structure

Comment: What have you tried? It will not be so helpful to you if we would just give you a solution... What will you learn from it? Try to go over some recursion tutorials and come up with some code. Ask here when you get errors or can't get it to work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a for loop to a recursive method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985040/how-do-i-convert-a-for-loop-to-a-recursive-method)